# How to extract top 5 sum values with their top 3 sum reasons?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I need to review this query:

```
=QUERY('BD3'!A:Q, "SELECT D,Q, SUM(M) WHERE I='W34' AND M>0 AND L='Huacho' GROUP BY D,Q ORDER BY SUM(M) DESC LIMIT 5",-1)
```

I obtain this:
[image: Obtained this]

But I need something like this:
[image: How it should be]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (specifically `Help others reproduce the problem`) and edit your question to include the example as text, not as an image - `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.`. Please include some example data as well.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

For the result you want, the correct SQL function should be:

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY D, Q ORDER BY SUM(M) DESC
```

You can check this answer for detail explanations:
[Array Formula to Rank Column A Partition by Column B And C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60834473/array-formula-to-rank-column-a-partition-by-column-b-and-c)

Comment: can you give an example?